# Do I need conduit for the exposed portion of a sub-panel feeder?

Tags: electrical

I am trying to install a 60 amp sub panel in my house to power my wife's saltwater tanks. I know I need 6/3 to go from main panel to sub panel. My question is I have to run it along the wall to get to the ceiling then down the wall to get to sub panel. What type of wire and do I need conduit? The sub panel will be just outside the backdoor under the porch.

Comment: Will it be outdoors in any way?

Comment: Will it be running somewhere where it will be exposed to any sort of physical damage?

Comment: It will be running along wall up to the garage ceiling. I have a bonus room above garage making it hard to run straight up.  the end will drop outside directly into the panel.  As my perspective it will be safe from physical damage.

Comment: Any answers to my question? Project on hold till I can get answer?